# Finding the affine transformation from ordered set A to set B

Tags: affine-geometry, linear-regression

I have an x-ray fluorescence detector which is used to measure the composition of different elements in a sample. The detector measures a signal which contains peaks at certain positions which correspond to different elements, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_fluorescence#/media/File:XRFScan.jpg). The output of the detector is counts per bin, not energy as shown in the image. I need to find the transformation values from the bins scale to the energy scale, which is of the form $ax + b$.

Since I know which elements are likely present, I know at which energies I can expect peaks to appear. These energies are theoretically always the same and so is their spacing, but due to noise it might vary slightly.

My goal is to find an algorithm which is able to find the transformation from the bin scale to the energy scale. And in order to make the algorithm more robust, I do not want it to break if a certain peak is absent or if I find additional peaks.

My initial thought was to select certain points from the bins set and the energy set and check which pair results in the lowest error. I would probably include here a lower bound that it will not use just one or two points which will have a very low error of course. Is there any method to tackle a problem such as this?

## Example

Say I measure a sample which has Zn, Cu and Fe. The expected peak positions of the K$\alpha$ and K$\beta$ peaks for these elements are at energies and measured bin positions (with added noise for the bin positions):

```
     Ka (bin)   Ka (keV)  Kb (bin)  Kb (keV)
Fe   1319       6.405     1467      7.059
Cu   1668       8.046     1870      8.904
Zn   1802       8.637     2034      9.57
```

Which looks like this when plotted and fitted. (Yes I cheated with the fitting by only taking the Kb points).

[image: bins versus energy]

However this would not work if I did not measure the Kb Fe peak at bin 1467, since I have 6 points in my energy set and only 5 in the bin set. It would also not work if I would measure an extra point at say bin 1500, which would not correspond to any element.

Comment: A linear transformation in one dimension would have the form $y=mx$, but you probably have in mind a more general function $y=mx+b$, which is first-degree ("linear") polynomial but an *affine transformation*.  Such a polynomial can be found by least-squares fitting ("linear regression").  Taking subsets of $A,B$ doesn't seem to make since for the "smallest error" because with one point in each subset the error will be zero.

Comment: @hardmath Yes I mean an affine transformation. As for the second point: Yes that is true that the error is zero with zero points, that could be easily fixed by putting a lower bound on the amount of points in a set.

Comment: @hardmath Is the question better now?

Comment: The Question is much better.   It may be hard to discern for Readers that you have no set of points $(x,y)$ to fit, but rather two sets, one of $x$ values and the other of $y$ values.  Note that the error would be zero not only for empty subsets, but also for subsets of size one and two.

Comment: The next thing to consider is the way an error in a fitting between two subsets will be measured. It sounds as if you want the transformation to match the largest possible subset allowing a fixed amount of this error, but I don't want to put this in my words.